# Python Recursive enumerate(), with Start Value Incrementation

Tags: python, recursion, graph, binary-tree, bipartite

I am attempting to create a Python function which parses through a bracket representation of a binary tree and outputs a line-by-line bipartite graph representation of it, where the partitions are separated by a "|", thus:

**Binary tree bracket representation:**

(((A, B), C), D)

**Bipartite graph relationship output:**

A B | C D

A B C | D

I approached it using recursion, maintaining each bipartite relationship line in a list, taking the original bracket notation string and the starting index of parsing as input.

```
def makeBipartRecursive(treeStr, index):
    bipartStr  = ""
    bipartList = []
    for ind, char in enumerate(treeStr, start=index):
        if char == '(':
            # Make recursive call to makeBipartRecursive
            indx = ind 
            bipartList.append(makeBipartRecursive(treeStr, indx+1))
        elif char == ')':
            group1 = treeStr[0:index-1] + treeStr[ind+1::]
            group2 = treeStr[index:ind]
            return group1 + " | " + group2
        elif char == ',':
            bipartStr += " " 
        else:
            # Begin construction of string
            bipartStr += char
```

Each time an open-parenthesis is encountered, a recursive call is made, beginning enumeration at the index immediately following the open-parenthesis, so as to prevent infinite recursion (Or so I think). If possible, try to ignore the fact that I'm not actually returning a list. **The main issue is that I encounter infinite recursion, where the enumeration never progresses beyond the first character in my string.** Should my recursive call with the incremented start position for the enumeration not fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the use of the `start` parameter of `enumerate`.  It does not mean *start the enumeration at this position* but *start counting from this index*.  See `help(enumerate)`:

```
|  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from start, which
|  defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
```

So basically each time you perform a recursive call you start again from the beginning of your string.

Comment: Super! Yeah I totally made an assumption there and didn't even think about that. Thank you so much.